# I don't understand the difference between React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between

```
const layout  = (props) => ();
```

and

```
const layout = (props) => {};
```

on React framework?

Comment: And fundamentally I would really recommend knowing the basics of JS/ES6 before trying to add React on top.

Comment: When you use `{}` that means you have to use `return` keyword to render a `JSX` element in react component. However, if you use `()` you don't need `return` keyword because it will by default return the component. However if you use `()` you can't use normal javascript because it returns directly

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that's helps me very good.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a `React` behavior, but it's how JS and arrow functions work. By using this syntax `() => ()` you are telling JS to return the value between parenthesis (without the need for an explicit `return`:

```js
const a = () => ('returned value')

const b = () => {'returned value'}

console.log(a()) // 'returned value'
console.log(b()) // undefined
```

so using `const a = () => ('returned value')` is the same as doing:

```
const a = () => {
  return 'returned value'
}
```